# Are the mail settings as given in preferences still programmatically accessible in V 11.2

Tags: email

In versions before 11.2 (and after 9) one could get the current settings as defined in the preferences (Internet & Email -> Mail Settings) with `Options[SendMail]`. As the options for `SendMail` have changed, this does now not work anymore. There now are only `MailAddressValidation` and `MailSettings` as options, and the latter is meant to hold an association which defines those paramters, but its default value is `Automatic` and there seems to be no documented way to programmatically access the values that have been set in the preferences.

Does anyone know a possibility to extract those programmatically anyway?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Settings are stored at `"ApplicationData\SendMail\Preferences\MailSettings.m"`  and `"ApplicationData\SendMail\Preferences\MailSettingsNew.m"` under the `$UserBaseDirectory`.

```
msp = FileNameJoin[
  {
   $UserBaseDirectory
   , "ApplicationData"
   , "SendMail"
   , "Preferences"
   , "MailSettings.m"
   }]

Query["MailSettings", "Server"][Get@msp]
```

Answer (score 8):

We can access the present settings using an undocumented global variable:

```
ExternalService`MailSettings`$MailSettings

(*
   <| AutoBcc->{},AutoCc->{},EncryptionProtocol->None,FromAddress->None,
      FromName->None,Password->Automatic,PortNumber->Automatic,
      ReplyTo->Automatic,Server->None,ServerAuthentication->Automatic,
      Signature->None,UserName:>$UserName
   |>
*)
```

This variable will reflect changes made by the user through the *Preferences* dialog.

Comment: interesting, it looks like this is just reading the file that rhermans detected via ``ResourceLocator`Private`getPreferenceFile["SendMail", \
"MailSettings", PreferencesRead]``. Interestingly there is also a corresponding file `"MailSettingsNew"`. I think the combination of your answers gives a quite complete picture...

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to rhermans and WReach my question is not only answered but it also is clear what is going on:

In version 11.2 the variable `` ExternalService`MailSettings`$MailSettings `` will  contain the settings as given in the preferences. The source of that information is the file `"ApplicationData\SendMail\Preferences\MailSettingsNew.m"`, while older versions used `"ApplicationData\SendMail\Preferences\MailSettings.m"` for that purpose.

Looking at the (readprotected) code for `` ExternalService`MailSettings`$MailSettings `` shows that it uses `` ExternalService`MailSettings`LoadMailSettings `` to load those settings. That does use the functions from the package `` "ResourceLocator`" `` to load that file using `Get` for the filename returned by `` ResourceLocator`Private`getPreferenceFile["SendMail", "MailSettingsNew", PreferencesRead] ``.

`` ExternalService`MailSettings`LoadMailSettings `` will also take care of converting an old settings file to a new one.